# Store is refreshed but dispatch is not rendering new view

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm Redux beginner. I started my journey yesterday. Probably it is really basic question that I can't resolve.

I want to update my view on sort button click. When I log (this.props.albums) it is updated but only in console.log. View is not updated.

Here is fetchAlbums function which I use to put data. this.props.albums is data that I use to sort and then update. As you see I use console.log(this.props.albums) and it's sorted. But my react view its not refreshed.

```
class AlbumSearchContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    albumInput: '',
  };

  searchForAlbums = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const albumName = this.state.albumInput;

    const api_call = await fetch(
      `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=album%3A${albumName}&type=album`,
      {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
      }
    );

    const data = await api_call.json();

    this.props.fetchAlbums(data.albums.items);
    this.setState({ albumInput: '' });
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ albumInput: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    let albumsList = [];

    if (this.props.albums.length > 0) {
      albumsList = this.props.albums.map(element => (
        <AlbumComponent
          key={element.id}
          name={element.name}
          image={element.images[1].url}
          artist={element.artists[0].name}
          release_date={element.release_date}
          total_tracks={element.total_tracks}
          id={element.id}
          href={element.href}
        />
      ));
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Jumbotron style={{ backgroundColor: '#1ED760' }}>
          <h1>Search using Album Name</h1>
          <SearchingForm
            searchForAlbums={this.searchForAlbums}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={this.state.albumInput}
          />

          {this.props.albums.length > 1 ? (
            <div>
              <p>
                <button
                  className="sortButton"
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.props.sortAlpha(this.props.albums);
                    console.log(this.props.albums);
                  }}
                >
                  Sort Alpha
                </button>

                <button
                  className="sortButton"
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.props.fetchAlbums(
                      this.props.albums.sort((a, b) => {
                        return (
                          new Date(b.release_date) - new Date(a.release_date)
                        );
                      })
                    );
                    console.log(this.props.albums);
                  }}
                >
                  Sort by date
                </button>
              </p>
            </div>
          ) : (
            console.log()
          )}
        </Jumbotron>
        <div className="albumContainer"> {albumsList}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  albums: state.albums,
});

const mapActionsToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchAlbums: albums => dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ALBUMS', payload: albums }),
    sortAlpha: albums =>
      dispatch({ type: 'SORT_ALBUMS_ALPHA', payload: albums }),
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapActionsToProps
)(AlbumSearchContainer);
```

I just want to update my view on this sort buttons click.

//edit when i start typing in my albumInput it's refreshed. But it's not refreshing on buttons click.

Comment: check redux official for https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux#why-isnt-my-component-re-rendering-or-my-mapstatetoprops-running

Comment: @medamis - show us your reducer

Comment: here it is: https://www.codepile.net/pile/zKXXbdKa

Comment: @medamis - You need to decide where to sort the albums, I think that the reducer is the best place to do that. Currently you are sorting `albums` twice. Once in the `onClick` and in the reducer as well.

Comment: @jank now code is updated I just sort it in reducer.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of mistakes in your logic:

- You are executing sorting algorithm in wrong place.
  Albums array is part of your state. Your state is passed into your component via props. Whenever albums array changes, your component will be updated.
- You are not dispatching the sort action.
  Basic lifecycle of redux applications is an endless chain of user action => state updates. When there is a user action (e.g. sort click), you should dispatch an action. And in your reducer, you should sort albums

**EDIT:** Regarding your comment, in redux world there is no such thing as

> I want to do this on click

at lesat not in implementation. When user clicks, only thing you have to do is dispatching an action. Once you have this mindset, separating actions and state updates it'd be more clear.

Comment: hmm. I think I made progres in your second ansswer. Here is my reducers.js https://www.codepile.net/pile/8gMQMygn 
I'm not sure about correct place to execute sorting algorithm. Of course I want to do this on click. Now when I updated my reducer code I execute like this 
onClick={() => {
                    this.props.sortAlpha(this.props.albums);
                    
                  }}

But its still not updated. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I just added one more part to my answer. And checked your code as well. In reducer, you have to return state from your actions. Just like you do it in default case. Create a new albums/artists object, and return that in state

Comment: My friend did you mean something like this? https://www.codepile.net/pile/AwqJA1WX

Comment: Yes. Don't forget to fix your FETCH_ALBUMS reducer logic. You have to return proper state from each action

Comment: Okay, cool. So the final thing is how to use this reducer correctly. Now when I try sort all data, view just dissapear. Of course when I logged it it is sorted correctly. Here is code that I use https://www.codepile.net/pile/9rdkRdQo

Thank you for your patience!

Comment: One side note: in your actions, you don't have to send albums again. The action is not related to that. It's better to reach albums data inside reducer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your fetchAlbums isn't working, but this should work:

```
searchForAlbums = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const albumName = this.state.albumInput;

    const res = fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=album%3A${albumName}&type=album`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(albums => {
        this.props.fetchAlbums(albums);
        this.setState({ albumInput: '' });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

Your reducer is missing an `album` state:

```
const initialState = {
    artists: {},
    albums: []
};
```

You are not updating your store correctly, this is the correct pattern:

```
const albums = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_ALBUMS:
            return { ...state, albums: action.payload };
        case SORT_ALBUMS_ALPHA:
            let newAlbums = action.payload.sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
                if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
                return 0;
            });

            return {...state, albums: newAlbums };
        case FETCH_ARTISTS:
            return {...state, artists: action.payload);
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Please check these modifications, and let us know the output

Comment: @medamis - check what is the value returned for albums from your API request and update the type of data in the initial state. Currently it is set to Array, if its an Object then change it accordingly.

Comment: return { ...state, albums: action.payload }; this line is not working. Just nothing happen when I try to fetch albums. But return (state = action.payload); is working probably it is inncorect because im not saving copy right now. SORT_ALBUMS_ALPHA also is not working.

Comment: from API it is array of objects.

Comment: @medamis - Please see the updated answer, You should avoid overriding your state. Also, try to check what you receive from your API and make adjustment where needed.

Comment: I tried your solution and when I submit form there is nothing in view. I can log this.props.artists but only in console. View is not refreshed. Here is logged this.props.artists https://www.codepile.net/pile/525jRxXp

Comment: just fetch action works perfectly here https://www.codepile.net/pile/JRnlmqAg when I use just return action.payload. But the problem is when i try to sort and render new state.  return { ...state, albums: newAlbums }; this is not working.